# Bootstrap column size equal to a specific column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have BootStrap 4 and I'm trying to get some column's height equal to another.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="container" style="overflow:hidden">
    <div class="row" style="overflow:hidden">
        <div class="col-md-8" id="firstColumn">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="secondColumn" style="overflow:auto">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My `secondColumn` has a higher height than `firstColumn`, but I want it to have the same height as `firstColumn` while also being scrollable.

I want to mention that my columns are in a modal which when user clicks a button loads data from my database and populates the modal. So on page load if I set their height equal it will not work.

Comment: Even though it's a duplicate this question is a little different from the others. It's asking how to shorten the divs, not increase them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I can recommend is to look at using the resize jQuery event to look at the heights of both divs and setting the height of the shorter to that of the taller.

Something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    firstHeight = $("#firstColumn").height();
    secondHeight = $("#secondColumn").height();
    if (firstHeight > secondHeight) {
        $("#secondColumn").height(firstHeight);
    } else {
        $("#firstColumn").height(secondHeight);
    }
}
```

It's likely you'd want this to run on page open too, so you could make the contents a named function that you can recall in both the ready and resize triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)!

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}

.colA {
  background-color: #EAE;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.colB {
  background-color: #AEE;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  max-height: 70px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="colA">
    One Line
  </div>
  <div class="colB">
    More<br/>
    than<br/>
    one<br/>
    line!
  </div>
</div>
```

Or via **Bootstrap 4** - Bootstrap 4 supports this natively. `row-eq-height`

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 5px solid yellow;
}

.colA {
  background-color: #EAE;
  line-height: 2em;
}

.colB {
  background-color: #AEE;
  max-height: 70px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div class="wrapper row row-eq-height">
  <div class="colA col-6">
    One Line
  </div>
  <div class="colB col-6">
    More<br/>
    than<br/>
    one<br/>
    line!
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** made scrollable `colB`
To make a col scrollable you have to set `height` or `max-height` and define overflow as shown in the examples.